# Must declare the scalar variable in Reporting services with Maps

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, maps, ssrs-2008, bing-maps

I have query in SSRS which gives me good results. Now, I want to include map in my report, dynamic map with Bing tiles and points from same data set as other report data. When I insert map I'm getting error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@username". No spatial data
>   available. The map display contains sample spatial data.

When I run my report from the browser, I get non interactive tiles with no points. What is going on here?
Query is given below. And it is SQL Server 2012 as data source.

```
SELECT [dbo].[ufnGetGroupNameFromVehicleId](se.VehicleId) Grupa
      ,v.Registration Vozilo
      ,[Timestamp] "Datum/Vreme"
      ,[SpeedLimit] "Ograničenje"
      ,[Speed] Brzina
      ,[DataSource] Izvor
      ,[Location] -- geography data type (contains only points)
  FROM [dbMobTrackOsm].[dbo].[SpeedExceeds] se
  join [Vehicle].[Vehicle] v
  on se.VehicleId = v.VehicleId
  where se.VehicleId in (select VehicleId from [Vehicle].[VehicleUser] vu where UserId = [dbo].[ufnGetUserId]((@username), (@pass)))
        and ((Speed - SpeedLimit) / (case SpeedLimit when 0 then 1.0 else SpeedLimit * 1.0 end)) > (@tolerance / 100.0)
        and [Timestamp] between @from and @to
```

In addition, I need to display these points on interactive map. If this is not the right way, can somebody suggest me the right one?

Comment: The query looks OK. If that error is on the map preview in design mode, that's OK too. The main thing is making sure your "Location" column is being mapped in the map dataset. Also, SSRS maps are not meant to be interactive other than basic drillthrough actions. Other tools like Tableau are better for that.

Comment: @StevenWhite Error was in inserting map. I checked embed map data in report and that is why it doesn't work. I unchecked it know and works fine.

Comment: @rbrundritt Se comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that the query is failing due to the @username value not being declared anywhere. As such there is no location data being returned by the query and the map isn't able to display. The map isn't the issue. Take a look at this part of your query and figure out where the @username value is set:

```
UserId = [dbo].[ufnGetUserId]((@username), (@pass)))
```